# How to deal with impossible dates for midasr package

Tags: r

I am using a package in R called midasr which helps me forecast monthly data using daily data as a regressor. For this purpose I need to make sure each month in a given year has an equal number of days. For example on months like February where it never goes to the 30th or the 31st day, I need to still be able to specify a value (NA) for that date, so as to maintain a consistent format. When I try specifying dates that never occur in real life, (2009 is a  non leap year, so day 29 doesnt happen) I get an NA under the date column as follows. Is there a way to work around this? I need it to show '2009-02-29'.

```
> as.Date('2009-02-29', format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] NA
> as.Date('2009-02-25', format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2009-02-25"
> as.Date('2009-02-27', format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2009-02-27"
> as.Date('2009-02-28', format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2009-02-28"
> as.Date('2009-02-29', format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] NA
```

Additional: I have also tried letting the 'impossible' Date remain as 'NA' and putting it in the right order in a data frame(Right below 28th Feb in this case). But when I turn it into a zoo object, the 'NA date' gets sent to the end of the time series so that didnt work.

Comment: 2009 is NOT a leap year...

Comment: @sparrow you did NOT read the question

Comment: I'm not sure if you could do this unless you just represented the dates as a string. R stores dates as number of days from janurary 1st 1970, so `as.numeric(as.Date('2009-02-28', format="%Y-%m-%d"))`
is  `14303` and `as.numeric(as.Date('2009-03-01', format="%Y-%m-%d"))` is `14304` so this is why you get an `NA` for Feb 29th--there is no integer between 14303 and 14304

Comment: sorry. But how do you want to specify an impossible date? Either you can have an NA, or have the impossible date as a character string: `"2009-02-29"`

Comment: Can you show more of your data structure? `midasr` is usually used with weekly and monthly aggregate data. It would help to see both the data and the function in the `midasr` package you want to use.

Comment: @hrbrmstr My daily data is just 2 columns, one with date and the other a value. The midasr package author told me I needed each month to have the same number of days and that I should pad NAs to the missing days (I decided to let each month have 31 days). Would you still like me to post a sample of my data?

Comment: Package **midasr** expects numeric vectors and does not need date information. So converting to zoo object is not really necessary. You could use zoo objects to make the padding easier, but in the end simple numeric vector should be passed. The answer by @IShouldBuyABoat is spot on. Do not convert the bogus dates to the type Date, keep it as character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your choice. I'm pretty sure that zoo can handle ordered character vectors for its index;

```
>  paste(2009, sprintf("%02s",rep(1:12, each=31)), sprintf("%02s", 1:31), sep="-") [55:65]
[1] "2009-02-24" "2009-02-25" "2009-02-26" "2009-02-27" "2009-02-28" "2009-02-29"
[7] "2009-02-30" "2009-02-31" "2009-03-01" "2009-03-02" "2009-03-03"

str (as.Date( paste(year, rep(1:12, each=31), 1:31, sep="-") ) )
 Date[1:372], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" "2009-01-04" ...
> as.Date( paste(2009, rep(1:12, each=31), 1:31, sep="-") ) [55:65]
 [1] "2009-02-24" "2009-02-25" "2009-02-26" "2009-02-27" "2009-02-28" NA          
 [7] NA           NA           "2009-03-01" "2009-03-02" "2009-03-03"
```

Do note that `paste` (like `data.frame`) will recycle short vectors which expelains why no `rep` is needed for '2009' and why the second `rep(.)` is only 31 elements long.

Comment: Once you figure out how to build proper format strings for `sprintf` it is very useful. Some people prefer `formatC`.