# How to make all the months to have an equal number of days (for example 22 days) for a MIDAS regression in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, forecasting

This is a follow up question for these two posts.

[How to deal with impossible dates for midasr package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572162/how-to-deal-with-impossible-dates-for-midasr-package)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77495/what-can-i-do-with-these-two-time-series

I need to use mls function in MIDAS package in R to transform the high frequency (daily) financial data to low frequency (quarterly) macroeconomic data.

The author  @mpiktas mentioned

> You must make all the months to have an equal number of days. And then
>   set frequency to that number. You can achieve that by discarding data,
>   padding NAs or extrapolating.

and

> You could use zoo objects to make the padding easier, but in the end
>   simple numeric vector should be passed.

I tried different ways to search and did not find an easy way to implement.

I use dplyr to get each month to have 31 days with 7-11 NA.

```
# generate the date vector
library(midasr)
library(dplyr)
library(quantmod) 
tsxdate <- as.Date( paste(1979, rep(1:12, each=31), 1:31, sep="-") )

for (year in 1980:2015){
    tsxdate <- c(tsxdate,as.Date( paste(year, rep(1:12, each=31), 1:31, sep="-") ))
    }
# transform to dataframe
tsxdate.df <- as.data.frame(tsxdate)
# get the stock market index from yahoo
tsxindex <- getSymbols("^GSPTSE",src="yahoo", from = '1977-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
# merge two data frame to get each month with 31 days
tsx.df <- left_join(tsxdate.df, tsxindex)
```

I doubt this caused a problem due to too many NAs.

I put the new daily data into MIDAS regression in R. It did not work. None of the weight functions work.

```
# since each month has 31 days. one quarter yy correspond to 93 days data. 
midas_r(midas_r(yy~trend+fmls(zz,30,93,nealmon) ,start=list(zz=rep(0,4))), Ofunction="nls")
```

Could you tell me how to make all the months to have an equal number of days?

**update:**

Finally, I got a way in `zoo` package with `aggregate`  and `first` function. It is not perfect, but it works and fast. `first` will add NAs according to the parameter.

I still need to figure out how to fit it into a MIDAS regression.

```
# get data
tsx <- getSymbols("^GSPTSE",src="yahoo", from = '1977-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
# subset 
# generate a zoo object
library(zoo)
tsx.zoo <- zoo(tsx$GSPTSE.Adjusted)
# group by yearmonth and take first 22 days data.
days <-aggregate(tsx.zoo, as.yearmon, first, 22)
```

It looks like this: each row is one month with 22 days data.

```
Jun 1979 1614.29      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
Jul 1979 1614.29 1598.73 1579.88 1582.57 1582.27 1576.19 1559.23 1529.81 1533.50 1547.66
Aug 1979 1554.14 1556.94 1553.84 1553.84 1551.95 1561.23 1562.52 1571.00 1578.08 1580.28
Sep 1979 1685.11 1657.58 1690.10 1720.92 1716.53 1711.34 1722.71 1714.63 1727.50 1724.51
Oct 1979 1749.05 1767.40 1775.98 1786.35 1800.12 1800.12 1735.88 1685.21 1681.52 1670.65
Nov 1979 1599.33 1606.81 1596.54 1592.94 1574.49 1569.20 1583.97 1608.70 1611.00 1619.78

Jun 1979      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
Jul 1979 1556.94 1546.86 1548.46 1553.54 1542.07 1543.17 1552.85 1566.01 1573.99 1564.12
Aug 1979 1596.64 1602.82 1615.09 1636.53 1653.09 1660.97 1657.78 1665.46 1674.44 1674.64
Sep 1979 1714.73 1717.53 1732.59 1736.48 1731.19 1732.49 1746.75 1754.33 1747.45      NA
Oct 1979 1639.03 1613.19 1616.29 1635.34 1593.44 1533.40 1522.12 1534.49 1517.24 1523.92
Nov 1979 1628.55 1621.57 1624.36 1627.56 1620.27 1647.51 1677.93 1683.81 1690.70 1698.97

Jun 1979      NA      NA
Jul 1979 1554.14      NA
Aug 1979 1674.24 1675.43
Sep 1979      NA      NA
Oct 1979 1538.68 1552.25
```

**update again:**

@mpiktas gives a better and right way to do it.

> 1 NAs should be padded at beginning of each period.
>
> 2 Data should be gather in the frequency of response variable. In my case, it is quarterly.

His function can be used in `aggregate` function in `zoo`. I guess it do the same job as `group_by` plus `do` in `dplyr`: split, operate, and give back a list of results. I try this

```
tsxdaily <- aggregate(tsx.zoo, yearqtr, padd_nas, 66)
```

`yearqtr` is the frequency of response variable.

Comment: You say that none of the weight functions work. What error message was given? Could you please post a reproducible example involving a call to `midas_r`?

Comment: I gather that your response variable is quarterly, so you need to align your daily data to quarters, not months.

Comment: Thank you @mpiktas. It works now. Yes, I use daily data to forecast quarterly GDP. I am comparing the MIDASr and Bayesian variable selection (spikeslab). I think weight function can reduce dimension. Other dimension reduction also should work. I would like to try something like Lasso or boosting. I am wondering if I can just skip weigh function and directly use other methods to reduce dimension.  Many researcher in their paper mention they still estimate parameters in weight functions even though they use other methods at the same time.

Comment: Which paper is that? Could you give a citation?

Comment: Hi @mpiktas, I am not sure if I need to start a new post. One of paper is [Variable Selection in Predictive MIDAS Models](https://ideas.repec.org/p/bfr/banfra/520.html). The author says `kernel mK() which smooths out the K past values of the variable xt` at page 6. And in his Bayesian variable selection section, he still estimate theta in weight function in page 11(`an Independence Chain Metropolis Hasting algorithm (iMH)
within the Gibbs sampler to draw the posterior conditional distribution of theta.`).

Comment: The author's [slides](http://www.seltenhut.com/clement.marsilli/me_files/Soutenance.pdf) is  clearer to show how he does the Bayesian variable selection within the MIDAS with weight function

Comment: Yes I think you should formulate another question (about dimensionality reduction) and it should go to stats.stackexchange.com. It might be that only few people can answer it, but formulating nice question sometimes is half way in getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way of how to add NAs.

First, note that MIDAS regression puts the emphasis on the last values of the period, so you need to put NAs in front, not in the back.

Suppose that we have the following dummy data:

```
> dt <- data.frame(Day=1:10,Quarter=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,4)),value=1:10)
> dt
   Day Quarter value
1    1       1     1
2    2       1     2
3    3       1     3
4    4       1     4
5    5       1     5
6    6       1     6
7    7       2     7
8    8       2     8
9    9       2     9
10  10       2    10
```

In this example there are two quarters, the first one has 6 days, the second one 4. Suppose we want to harmonize the data, so that the quarter has 7 days (for example).

Define simple function which adds NAs at the beginning of the data:

```
padd_nas <- function(x, desired_length) {
    n <- length(x)
    if(n < desired_length) {
        c(rep(NA,desired_length-n),x)
    } else {
        tail(x,desired_length)
        }
}
```

Here is an example illustrating how this function works:

```
> padd_nas(1:4,7)
[1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  4
>
```

Now add NAs for each quarter and make sure that the data is ordered by day:

```
library(dplyr)
pdt <- dt %>% arrange(Day) %>% group_by(Quarter) %>% do(pv = padd_nas(.$value, 7))  

> pdt
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

  Quarter       pv
1       1 <int[7]>
2       2 <int[7]>
```

To get the padded result simply use `unlist` on column `pv`:

```
> pv <- pdt$pv %>% unlist
> pv
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA NA  7  8  9 10
```

Now we can prepared this for MIDAS regression with `mls`. Suppose that only last 3 days are relevant for each quarter:

```
> library(midasr)
> mls(pv, 0:2, 7)
     X.0/m X.1/m X.2/m
[1,]     6     5     4
[2,]    10     9     8
```

Compare this with original data `dt`.

This approach can be generalized for any low and high frequency data configuration.

Comment: Thanks @mpiktas. It works. It makes life much easier. This line gives me all I want.  And I find your function also works with `aggregate` function in zoo package.  `tsxdaily <- aggregate(tsx.zoo, as.yearqtr, padd_nas, 66)` This approach is very similar dplyr. And I just realized that  `do` in `dplyr` can give a list of object, which is very useful. Thank you again.